# How do I make fancybox work from Google Maps InfoBox on mobile (iphone safari)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, fancybox, infobox

**I'm trying to create a Google Maps InfoBox that contains some textual info and also a google sphere which opens with fancybox.**

**My first solution** was to use Google Maps InfoWindow, which actually worked - fancybox iframe was opening from the InfoWindow on desktop and mobile.

*-Here is my working solution for desktop and mobile with InfoWindow: http://spoti.lv/infowindow/*

**I needed to customize** the InfoWindow, and so I found the InfoBox, which works in a similar way but has more customization options.

**The problem** was that InfoBox did not behave like the original InfoWindow.

1.At first the fancybox did not work at all, it was just directing me to the url specified in a href.

2.Then I found out that setting the enableEventPropagation option of InfoBox to true made it work - on desktop but not on iphone safari browser.

*-Here is my working solution for desktop only with InfoBox: http://spoti.lv/infobox/*

**The Big Question: How do I make fancybox work from Google Maps InfoBox on mobile (iphone safari)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your content, set it to be like this:

```
var content = '<div id="gWindow"><a data-apply="fancybox.iframe fancybox-effects-b" data-origin="iframe.html?panoid='+ pano +'" title="' + name + ' - ' + city + ', ' + street + '" href="javascript:;"><div id="gImgWrap"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x200&fov=120&heading=350&pitch=-2&pano=' + pano + '&sensor=false" /></div></a><div id="gWrap"><h3>' + name + '</h3><span id="gCity">' + city + '</span>, ' + street + '<br /><span id="gRest">' + 'Darba laiks: ' + time + '<br />' + 'Cena: ' + price + ' EUR' + '<br /><a href="http://' + web + '" target="_blank">' + web + '</a></span></div></div>';
```

then when defining your event extend it so there are no overlaps

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {

        return function() {

            infobox.setContent(content);

            infobox.open(map, marker);

            resetMapClickEvents();

        }

    })(marker, content));
```

and lastly add the reset command

```
var resetMapClickEventsIndex = 0, resetMapClickEvents = function(){
// because you reset event after ever info box created,
// make sure it gets recreted when reupdated
// and does not recreate if fancy is triggered
resetMapClickEventsIndex++;
$('[data-origin]').unbind().bind('click', function(){
    if($(this).data('index') !== resetMapClickEventsIndex){
        $(this).data('index', resetMapClickEventsIndex)
        $(this).fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            href: $(this).data('origin'),
            modal: true,
            transitionIn: 'elastic',
            transitionOut: 'elastic',
            speedIn: 600, 
            speedOut: 200
        });
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

};

have not tried the code, but this should give you the concept of my theory.